# Are there any options for logging request times in grpc-node?

Tags: grpc, trace, distributed-system, grpc-node

Are there any options for logging request times in grpc-node? I've been able to log response times using opentelemetry & jaegar (to display response times). I couldn't find any npm packages for this either, but just wanted to ask you guys if you did find any options for grpc-node.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a package to do it, you can do it using a simple gRPC client interceptor.

This is how you would do it in Golang. Just check how you can create a gRPC interceptor in Node. Sorry for not having a JS example, hope it helps some how.

```
func UnaryRequestTImeInterceptor() grpc.UnaryClientInterceptor {
    return func(
        ctx context.Context,
        method string,
        req interface{},
        reply interface{},
        cc *grpc.ClientConn,
        invoker grpc.UnaryInvoker,
        opts ...grpc.CallOption,
    ) error {
        start := time.Now()
        err := invoker(ctx, method, req, reply, cc, opts...)
        reqTime := time.Since(start)
        return err
    }
}
```